# Why should photons obey the rules of causality?

Tags: special-relativity, photons

This may have a quick answer, but it has been on my mind so here it goes: why, if according to special relativity, do photons obey the rules of causality, if they are inherently timeless. According to special relativity, wouldn't a particle travelling at light speed experience no time, and therefore, why would it be expected to obey the rules of causality as experienced by those not going the speed of light?

Comment: What does "obey the rules of causality" mean?

Comment: Cause before effect, mostly, but really anything involving time.

Comment: I don't think that helps clarify it very much.

Comment: Causality is very hard to define in a technical sense for physics. Philosophers also work with various definitions of causality, some of which overlap with the physics definitions. There is no way to answer a question like this unless you specify a definition. "Cause before effect" is not a definition, because you haven't defined "cause" or "effect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a photon that is emitted and then absorbed. For any "timely" observer (that is, anyone that sees the time flowing) will see the emission of the photon to happen before the absorption, and everyone will agree on which one comes first. So, whatever happens when and where the photon was emitted, cannot affect the place it will be absorbed before it arrives.

The ordering of light-like separated events is an invariant of Special Relativity. They have to follow causality because everyone else does, and they will all agree on it.

Comment: +1, nice answer but i dont if this is what the OP asks for

Comment: @NikosM. then I don't understand the question... Keefer, is this what you are after?

Comment: To be clear i have the impression the OP wants sth more mathematical, maybe i am wrong

Comment: For example, my original wondering of the question came from reading about quantum entangled photons, which, in certain experiments, effect seemed to proceed cause, and information would travel between them seemingly instantaneously (within the degree of accuracy of the equipment), but that would seem to violate special relativity. The issue in my mind arose that time was a factor in measuring speed and photons do not, for the lack of a better word, 'experience' time.

Comment: @KeeferRowan I don't think I understand it completely. Electrons can show entanglement, so do photons. But you cannot use entanglement to transmit information faster than light.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help the answer to this question, I would recommend the distinction between two things: You are referring to **photons, that is lightlike movements**. If you "remove" this lightlike movement (and the photons) from your consideration, there will remain **two events**: one event of emission and one event of absorption. Both events should have a timely dimension. And the first event seems to happen before the second event so that there is no causality issue.